# Object repeated in DetailView's context

Tags: django, django-views

I have the following view in which I add extra context to send similar post to the template.

```
class PostDateDetailView(DateDetailView):
    queryset = Post.published.all()
    date_field = "publish"
    month_format='%m'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        obj = self.get_object()
        post_tags_pks = obj.tags.all().values_list('pk', flat=True)
        similar_posts = self.queryset.filter(tags__in=post_tags_pks).exclude(pk=obj.pk)
        similar_posts = similar_posts.annotate(same_tags=Count('tags')).order_by('-same_tags','-publish')[:3]
        context["similar_posts"] = similar_posts
        print(context)
        return context
```

The view works right, but when I print the context I get 'object' and 'post' (are the same object)

```
{'object', 'post', 'view', 'similar_posts'}
```

When I look into the function get_context_data from SingleObjectMixin it seems the result will be always duplicated: I mean, there will always be a self.object ['object'], and a context_object_name ['post'].

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = {}
            if self.object:
                context['object'] = self.object
                context_object_name = self.get_context_object_name(self.object)
                if context_object_name:
                    context[context_object_name] = self.object
            context.update(kwargs)
            return super().get_context_data(**context)
```

I would like to know if either there is a reason for that or if I'm missing something.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: To make it more uniform, for example you can make a template that uses `object` and use it in all views.

Comment: I did not test that, but I think that 'get_context_object_name'  get always the model name, in this case Post.

Comment: no, you can also add an attribute `context_object_name` to the view to specify under what name to pass the object.

Comment: you are right, I added `context_object_name = 'object`' explicitly and there are no duplicated object. But, obviously, template should have to uses object to receive it. Thank you!